# change order of array elements in php file

Tags: php, text

Not sure about how to title this post.

I just inherited a set of internationalization documents, each containing an array of key value pairs.  I recognize the methodology is not ideal, it is however, what I'm stuck with given my role, the time and resources I have available.  These lists were created by hand and items were constantly being added haphazardly to keep up with demand.  The examples below are simplified, there are ~21 language files, each with 100+ entries.

The array from one file will have elements something like the below:

```
'download_high' => 'Vysoké',
'download_low' => 'Nízké',
'download_med' => 'Strední',
'download_video' => 'Stáhnout video',
```

While another file will have something like the following:

```
'download_video' => 'Descargar Video',
'download_high' => 'Alta',
'download_med' => 'Media',
'download_low' => 'Baja',
```

For the most part, the elements are ordered consistently, but there are plenty of exceptions and it complicates maintaining the files.  I was wondering if there's a way to make the order / formatting of these arrays consistent either via an IDE or notepad++ plugin, etc.  I don't want to order them alphabetically necessarily as there are logical groupings that won't translate well to alphabetical sorting since only some of the variables are namespaced.  Doing it by hand is almost out of the question, but it would be nice if there were some way to specify an order and have some kind of text manipulation tool batch process the files.  I'm not all that familiar with php, so I don't know that it would be worth it for me to do this via code unless it's very simple.

Comment: Why don't you use a spreadsheet, and then you can sort it alphabetically (and if this isn't perfect, create a formula in the second column to change it to something that you can sort by)?

Comment: Can you give an example of how the code looks that makes it messy?

Comment: I added some regex you could use. I can't fine tune it without knowing more about the code you're trying to fix.

Comment: @Walkerneo - added an example to the post

Comment: @wezten - that's certainly an option, but it's probably too labour intensive for me to stay in my timebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the situation I'd do it semi-automatically on an as-needed basis. That is, it sounds to me like you're charged with maintaining these files, and it's in the maintenance that the sorting becomes an issue.

For each language file formatted like:

```
<?php
$something = array(
  'download_video' => 'Descargar Video',
  'download_high' => 'Alta',
  ...
  'download_med' => 'Media',
  'download_low' => 'Baja',
);
```

1. Issue a `sort lang.es.php` command in bash, or via however you prefer to sort something.
2. Open the file for editing.
3. Delete the array declaration.
4. Copy/paste the sorted lines from #1.

Honestly, it was a super bad idea for your predecessor to effectively hard-code something like this. It would be much better if this were stored via CSV, XML, pg/mySQL, etc where you could at least invoke an editor that understands the data format.

Comment: I've got a solution to it as of last night.  It's so specific I'm not going to bother posting it. I'm going to check your answer as the general solution as I think it would work for more people.  And yes, I completely agree about the hard coded associative array being the worst choice for scaling.  This project was a one off and the client won't pay to refactor, so I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function called [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). You could run the code and then print it with the function.

Personally, I would run some regex in notepad++ to do it.

**Edit**: In notepad++, you can do a find/replace with regex.

In the "Find what" field, put `\s*'(.+?)'\s*=>\s*'(.+?)'\s*(?:(,)|\s*$)\s*`

In the "Replace with" field, put `'$1' => '$2'$3\n`

This will turn something like:

```
'download_high'         =>  'Vysoké',
    'download_low'=>                    

    'Nízké',
'download_med'
=>
'Strední'
,
    'download_video'    =>  'Stáhnout video',
'filter_by' => 'Filtrovat podle'
,




'footer_contact' => 'Kontakt'
```

into

```
'download_high' => 'Vysoké',
'download_low' => 'Nízké',
'download_med' => 'Strední',
'download_video' => 'Stáhnout video',
'filter_by' => 'Filtrovat podle',
'footer_contact' => 'Kontakt'
```

*note: This is written with the assumption that all keys and values use single quotes and that neither keys nor values have any escaped single quotes inside.

Comment: Sounds interesting about the regex and notepad++, can you elaborate a bit on what that solution might look like?

Comment: @Shane, I'll whip something up for you :)

Comment: Trying this now.  +1 regardless if this answers my question, thank you!

Comment: Definitely interesting in that this can format the lines consistently.  Unfortunately I had some escaped apostrophe's that created a problem, but I think this is a step in the right direction.  I may look at the export method you mentioned above or just whip up a quick file to print it all out to the screen and copy paste it back in

Comment: @Shane Haha, yeah, I figured that might happen, but I couldn't be sure what kind of keys/values you'd have. I'll fix it up a bit.

Comment: @Shane, Try it now :). Eventually, there will be few enough edge cases where fixing things manually will be easy.

Comment: had some comma craziness there, not sure what happened but it looks like it was removing some line breaks?

Comment: @Shane, You're going to have to post more of the code for me to know what needs to be included in the regex

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19844/discussion-between-walkerneo-and-shane)

Comment: I forgot I made a change to the "Replace with" field. There was supposed to be a newline at the end of it. Should work now

Comment: perfect, thanks!  As I mentioned in chat I think I'm going to finish this using php to fix the php files. :)

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't suggest using arrays and php files etc if you are going to have a continuously growing list. take the couple minutes now to set up mysql and pull from a database with your desired parameters. NEAT, FAST, EFFECIENT AND SCALABLE.

Comment: Thanks, but not possible.  That's way beyond the scope of what I'm tasked to do.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to simply build a script to load all those arrays into a database where they can be maintained more easily.  Of course you would need to make sure you database table/fields were set up for UTF-8 character sets and collations.

Comment: Completely appreciate the suggestion and yes, that would be a better solution.  Not an option given my role and responsibilities on this project.

Comment: Are these array each in different files per language?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's probably connected via some kind of dynamic include.  I don't have a lot of time to flesh out the entire list, so I'm looking for quick n' dirty ways to make it as easy as possible. :)

Comment: Well if there is a one-to-one correlation between languages and files, you might be able to use a diff tool like Beyond Compare to at least speed up the manual organization process.  You could get one language file the way so want it and then compare to the others. The diff will make it easy to see if the files you are comparing to at least have the array keys in the same order, and if not, make it easy for you to cut/paste them where you want them.

Comment: Was using that and got flustered with the entries being out of sequence, there are soooo many.  Is there a way to use beyond compare to fix sequence correction?

Comment: Not that I know of. The other thing you might try is reading in the arrays with a script and then have that script output new PHP files with the arrays in the order you want.

Comment: I think... that last one is going to have to be the solution.  I was hoping for some kind of IDE based fix, but I don't think there is one (that request is way into corner cases and probably a tall order for an IDE).

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in understanding that you have already gotten your data into PHP arrays? At this point you could just do this to sort the keys. This would make the ordering consistent:

```
ksort($array);
```

Comment: I think the issue is that he doesn't care about the order of the array keys at runtime. He is concerned about how they are order in the code itself.

Comment: The tricky thing here is I am sorting the array in the actual php file, not the data itself.  There's a human element in editing these files that makes discrepancies in the sort order of these files a nuisance.  It would be more like some kind of loop / array.push method and then write it out to a file, just not sure how that would look in php.